# how to pull message data from discord.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, caching, discord.js

Discord.js is an API for Discord that allows the developers to make plugins for the program, discord. here's the link to the API code it's in js, https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/

Discord is setup to be like a server where you connect and chat on channels, my problem is how do I pull the message data from the channels.

What they did is setup all the channels in a JSON cache and within the channel, objects is another cache with the messages objects(what documentation says). But when I get to the message cache all I see is `messages: Cache { limit: 1000 } }`. How do I pull all the message objects from the channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those using discord.js v8 or lower.

If you want to pull all the message objects from the channel I recomend ignoring the cach and instead using `getChannelLogs(channel, limit, options, callback)` Which will allow you to fetch up to 100 messages at once, but those messages do not have to be cached within discord.js. You can quite easily create a recursive function that on the callback fetches more messages to fetch as many messages as you want.

That said server.channel.messages will be all of the messages in it that discord.js has cached. If it appears empty chances are no-one sent a message since the bot was activated.

source: http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_client.html#getchannellogs-channel-limit-options-callback

Comment: This has now been changed to [`.fetchMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages)

Comment: @OllyBritton The person who asked this question was using discord.js v8 or lower. Assuming they didn't migrate this is still the correct answer for them. I've edited my question to make the distinction clear, if you want to leave an answer for users using the newer branch of the library that may be better as a different answer.

Comment: Oh geez v8 xD Dayum its nice to see how far we've come